# Setting jagged array values within a class

Tags: c#, arrays, instantiation

I'm having trouble understanding this problem with creating a jagged array in C#. If you look at the code below, it compiles fine. But if I were to take the 2 lines that are assigning values to the array "places" and move them from within the method to within the class itself, the compiler starts complaining with a lot of strange errors.

At first I thought that its because of the usage of the 'new' keyword within a class (a class being just a definition whereas 'new' refers to an instance... you can't have an instance within a definition, can you?). But then I noticed the usage of the 'new' keyword in the initialization of "places" was OK even though it was initialized within the class. Please explain.

```
public class Place
{
string[][] places = new string[2][];
   public void enumerate()
   {
     places[0] = new string[] { "Canada", "United States" };
     places[1] = new string[] { "Calgary", "Edmonton", "Toronto" };

     Console.WriteLine(places[0][1]);
   }
}
```

EDIT: to be explicit, the error is produced when running

```
public class Place
{
string[][] places = new string[2][];
places[0] = new string[] { "Canada", "United States" };
places[1] = new string[] { "Calgary", "Edmonton", "Toronto" };
   public void enumerate()
   {
     Console.WriteLine(places[0][1]);
   }
}
```

errors received "array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a "new" expression)" "invalid tokens =, {, in class" "namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods"

Comment: Why would you use a jagged array for this? It would be better served as class objects.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Ignore the meaning of the values used. It is a completely meaningless array. I'm just wondering why it won't compile.

Comment: How does that not compile? It did for me output = `United States`.

Comment: DonA. I appreciate you looking through this but if you re-read my post I said it DOES compile, however, it DOESN'T when the 2 lines are moved into the class, rather than the method.

Comment: Right, I mean what errors? I don't get any. Can you show us how you initialize this class?

Comment: I just edited it to show the script that shows errors. (simply moved the value assignments for "places" in the class rather than the method.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully answer your question. I instantiated the class like this in main():             Place map = new Place(); map.enumerate();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can initialize an jagged array, but the syntax is slightly different:

```
public class Place
{
    private string[][] places = new string[2][]
    {
        new string[] { "Canada", "United States" },
        new string[] { "Calgary", "Edmonton", "Toronto" },
    };

    public void enumerate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(places[0][1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that solves that. Thank you. I'm still fuzzy on why this is a special case with arrays? And i'm not familiar with the syntax you used (encapsulating an array).

Comment: It is simply the syntax for array declarations and initialization, some examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Alberto. I suppose that's just the way its done with arrays and I will get used to the syntax.